# fatal error: gegl-buffer-iterator.h: No such file or directory

Tags: ubuntu, gimp

I'm trying to compile gimp (git version), and I installed gegl 0.1.2 without problems.
The problem is when I try make gimp.
I don't know why happend this error
help!

Comment: Full error log, please.

Answer (score 0):

You have to compile git version of gegl and babl:

```
$ git clone git://git.gnome.org/gegl
$ git clone git://git.gnome.org/babl
```

If you are getting this error while compiling babl:

```
/home/arzeth/compile/babl/babl/babl-types.h:23:2: error: #error "babl-version.h must not be included directly, include babl.h instead."
```

then remove these lines in those files:

```
#ifndef BABL_INSIDE_BABL_H
#error "babl-version.h must not be included directly, include babl.h instead."
#endif
```